# changing text input to select in wordpress using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a WordPress module abase to get some data from database and send them to a form. The problem is, that abase form does not allow to use select input. Because of that I am trying to convert text input to a select. I created `function toSelect`, to which I pass id of element and list of options (for testing I put id of element to function definition).

```
function toSelect(itemid,valuelist) {
    var out = '';
    out += '<select id="bus311mtd_2_status" style="width:50px;">';
    for (i=0; i < valuelist.length; i++) {
        out += '<option value="'+valuelist[i]+'">'+valuelist[i]+'</option>';
    }
    out += '</select>';
    alert(out);
    $("#bus311mtd_2_status").replaceWith(out);
    //$("#bus311mtd_2_status").replaceWith('<input type="text" value="zamontowane">');
}
```

`alert(out)` gives nice select input code, but `$("#bus311mtd_2_status").replaceWith(out)` does not work.

Even something like: `$("#bus311mtd_2_status").replaceWith('<input type="text" value="zamontowane">')` doesn't work.

Element with id **bus311mtd_2_status** for sure exists (i.e. changing its value using `document.getElementById()` works fine)

Maybe jQuery doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine for me. Perhaps it's your function call. I used:

```
toSelect(null, ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

`itemid` doesn't appear to be used in the function.

Here's a fiddle with your code working:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/Lko6aftf/

Here's a slightly optimized version of the function, that uses the `itemid` argument:

```
function toSelect2(itemid,valuelist) {
    var html = '<select id="' + itemid + '" style="width:50px;"><option>' +
        valuelist.join('</option><option>') +
        '</option></select>';
    $('#' + itemid).replaceWith(html);
}

toSelect2('myInput2', ['d', 'e', 'f']);
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer above should to appear as the comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer and optimization. I used itemid initially but because of problems I temporarily replaced it with id of some existing element to make sure that the problem is somwhere else.

All the code until first alert works fine and alert(out) gives the popup window with text:

```
<select id="bus311mtd_2_status" style="width:50px;"><option value="ready">ready</option><option value="awaiting">awaiting</option></select>
```

This works as was expected. But the problem starts with the next line.

I wanted to show that even such an easy code like below doesn't work.

```
$("#bus311mtd_2_status").replaceWith('<input type="text" value="zamontowane">');
```

So it looks like the jQuery was not supported.

And I've got another observation: within script tags no empty lines are allowed (the code doesn't work if they are present).

Comment: Please check the console for any error. **replaceWith**  should work correctly. There is no issue with the statement above. However you can use an alternative if you wish to. `$("#bus311mtd_2_status ").after('<input type="text" value="zamontowane">').remove();`

Comment: I got the following error: TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Please make sure you have attached jquery script in you code or check via `$.fn.jquery` on console. it will return a version number. If it doesn't, Please add jquery plugin to your code. and update my code as `jQuery("#bus311mtd_2_status ").after('<input type="text" value="zamontowane">').remove();`

Comment: That was the issue. Now it works fine. But just one more thing: elements after replacement get no style from current theme (they are free from any styling). Is there any way to attach the style form current theme?

Comment: if your style is coming from some short of css code than copy them in a css class and use that in you input tag. And if it is coming from the JS/Jquery then recall the function who is responsible for styling other similar elements. Or use jquery css method for applying custom css property.

Comment: My theme didn't take into account elements like select, so I added them to selectors in style.css inside my theme directory. And that helped. Thank you for your help.